# When I do GotoType in resharper, it opens the diff view (if it's open) rather than opening the file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, resharper-2017

I'm having a problem where VS+Resharper in combination take me to what I consider the wrong file when using resharper_gototype.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, Resharper Ultimate 2017.2.2

How to repro:

- Make a change to a file containing class C
- View differences - there is now a tab called "Diff - C.cs"
- Make sure the original file isn't open.
- use Resharper.Resharper_GoToType for class C
- The tab containing the diff will open up.

Expected behavior: The normal file of the class would open up, just as if the diff hadn't been open.

I think this happens because VS considers a diff of a file to be "the file" when extensions ask "is the file open?".  Is there a way to turn this off? I don't want it.

The same thing happens when you open a file, and then the annotated version of the file, and do Edit.GoTo - even though you have the annotated version open, using GoTo on an annotated file will change the tab in focus to the main tab, not the annotated one.  This is a problem because when you call Tfs.Annotate on a file, after it opens, the location you were at isn't preserved.